# What is the SQL query to check whether a database is present or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my program I created a new database by reading a value from a TextField. The database creation was successful. But if there is already a database with the same name, it will result in error. So I decided to check whether the database is present or not before creation. How can I check it ?

I know how to check whether a table is present in a database or not. My code for it is -

```
        preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema.tables\n" +
                  "WHERE table_schema = 'project' AND table_name = 'user'");
        rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int chk = rs.getInt(1);

        if(chk!=1)
        {
          preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("create table user (staffname varchar(30) primary key)");
          preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
```

I do it in this way. So please tell me how to check a database is present or not in this way.

Will this code work ? -

```
 preparedStatement = connect
                .prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)FROM information_schema\n" +
                  "WHERE table_schema = "+dbName+"");
        rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int chk = rs.getInt(1);

        if(chk!=1)
        {            
        int resultset = statement.executeUpdate("create database " + dbName );

        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName+"?"
                        + "user=root&password=virus");
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        }
```

Comment: Don't you confuse "database" and "table" terms?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]'
```

If the result is 1 it exists.

You can also use:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'dbname';
```

If it exists, you get one row.